# adding a png path as an layer in mapbox gl

Tags: angular, mapbox

I have a png file path as a source for adding layer in mapbox gl.I tried examples in mapbox gl but it is not working as expected.

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-image/

I referred to the above link but it is showing error in code as :

```
"Argument of type '{ "id": string; "type": "symbol"; "source": { "type": "geojson"; "data": { "type": "FeatureCollec...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Layer'.
 Types of property 'source' are incompatible.
 Type '{ "type": "geojson"; "data": { "type": "FeatureCollection"; "features": { "type": "Feature"; "geo...' is not assignable to type 'string | VectorSource | RasterSource | GeoJSONSource | ImageSource | VideoSource | GeoJSONSourceRaw'.
 Type '{ "type": "geojson"; "data": { "type": "FeatureCollection"; "features": { "type": "Feature"; "geo...' is not assignable to type 'GeoJSONSource'.
 Property 'setData' is missing in type '{ "type": "geojson"; "data": { "type": "FeatureCollection"; "features": { "type": "Feature"; "geo...'."
```

Can someone help me with how should I proceed further ?

Comment: which version of angular you are using??

Comment: i am using angular 5.2